# I finished the game and after the credits it took me back to before I finished the game.

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I just got done beating the elite four and fight the guardian in pokemon sun and after the credits scene. It took me back to the elite four before I beat them. So, I guess what I'm trying to say is why did it do that? and how do I prevent that from happening again?

Answer (score 0):

I just went ahead and finish the game again and this time it did not take me back to the elite four. I don’t know why it did that the first time but it’s good now.